# Set default value for enum collection

Tags: java, enums

I have the below class:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
public class User {
   @ElementCollection 
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    Collection<SystemRole> sysRole;
}
```

and the `SystemRole` is an `enum`.

```
public enum SystemRole {
    ADMIN,ORGANIZER,USER
}
```

I am wondering how can i set the default value of `USER`, for the attribute `sysRole` in the `User` class?

I mean, by default, all the instances of user class  have the `USER` role.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use instance initialization syntax:

```
Collection<SystemRole> sysRole = EnumSet.of(SystemRole.USER);
```

Comment: Thx I didn’t know that one.

Comment: Is there a way to do the same thing with an Object?

Comment: Found it : Collections.singleton("")

Comment: Also, new in Java 9, we have `Set.of(obj1, obj2, ...)` or `List.of(obj1, obj2, ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following :

```
Collection<SystemRole> sysRole=Arrays.asList(new SystemRole[]{SystemRole.User});
```